# Not able to use a config created in a java library

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, maven, spring-autoconfiguration

I am creating java jar library (maven) which will contain common configuration & util classes used in many services. My project is not multi-modules, so creating a new maven project.
The configuration class I am not able to use in my project. Found out there are 2 approach for this from below mentioned references.

[Reference1](https://medium.com/trendyol-tech/how-to-write-a-spring-boot-library-project-7064e831b63b)

[Reference2](https://grantlittle.me/index.php/2020/08/30/create-a-spring-boot-starter-library/)

1. Adding entry in resoruces/META-INF/spring.factories in the library project (auto-configure).
   It is giving error of class not found. Also added package of library in scanPackage attribute of Spring Boot Application. Src code is there after all the text.

   Error: The project which uses the library is not able to find class of ouath of spring related which is a dependency in the library class

> For the full error stacktrace, please see the following collapsed snippet:
>
> ```js
> 12:41:07.826 [main] ERROR org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication - Application run failed
> org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanDefinitionStoreException: Failed to process import candidates for configuration class [com.satishch.microspace.nri.security.ReferenceSecurityConfig]; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Unresolvable class definition for class [com.satishch.microspace.nri.security.ReferenceSecurityConfig]
> at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassParser.processImports(ConfigurationClassParser.java:610) ~[spring-context-5.2.12.RELEASE.jar:5.2.12.RELEASE]
> at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassParser.doProcessConfigurationClass(ConfigurationClassParser.java:311) ~[spring-context-5.2.12.RELEASE.jar:5.2.12.RELEASE]
> at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassParser.processConfigurationClass(ConfigurationClassParser.java:250) ~[spring-context-5.2.12.RELEASE.jar:5.2.12.RELEASE]
> at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassParser.processImports(ConfigurationClassParser.java:600) ~[spring-context-5.2.12.RELEASE.jar:5.2.12.RELEASE]
> at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassParser.access$800(ConfigurationClassParser.java:111) ~[spring-context-5.2.12.RELEASE.jar:5.2.12.RELEASE]
> at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassParser$DeferredImportSelectorGroupingHandler.lambda$processGroupImports$1(ConfigurationClassParser.java:812) ~[spring-context-5.2.12.RELEASE.jar:5.2.12.RELEASE]
> at java.util.ArrayList.forEach(ArrayList.java:1257) ~[?:1.8.0_191]
> at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassParser$DeferredImportSelectorGroupingHandler.processGroupImports(ConfigurationClassParser.java:809) ~[spring-context-5.2.12.RELEASE.jar:5.2.12.RELEASE]
> at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassParser$DeferredImportSelectorHandler.process(ConfigurationClassParser.java:780) ~[spring-context-5.2.12.RELEASE.jar:5.2.12.RELEASE]
> at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassParser.parse(ConfigurationClassParser.java:193) ~[spring-context-5.2.12.RELEASE.jar:5.2.12.RELEASE]
> at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassPostProcessor.processConfigBeanDefinitions(ConfigurationClassPostProcessor.java:319) ~[spring-context-5.2.12.RELEASE.jar:5.2.12.RELEASE]
> at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassPostProcessor.postProcessBeanDefinitionRegistry(ConfigurationClassPostProcessor.java:236) ~[spring-context-5.2.12.RELEASE.jar:5.2.12.RELEASE]
> at org.springframework.context.support.PostProcessorRegistrationDelegate.invokeBeanDefinitionRegistryPostProcessors(PostProcessorRegistrationDelegate.java:280) ~[spring-context-5.2.12.RELEASE.jar:5.2.12.RELEASE]
> at org.springframework.context.support.PostProcessorRegistrationDelegate.invokeBeanFactoryPostProcessors(PostProcessorRegistrationDelegate.java:96) ~[spring-context-5.2.12.RELEASE.jar:5.2.12.RELEASE]
> at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.invokeBeanFactoryPostProcessors(AbstractApplicationContext.java:707) ~[spring-context-5.2.12.RELEASE.jar:5.2.12.RELEASE]
> at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:533) ~[spring-context-5.2.12.RELEASE.jar:5.2.12.RELEASE]
> at org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.context.ServletWebServerApplicationContext.refresh(ServletWebServerApplicationContext.java:143) ~[spring-boot-2.3.8.RELEASE.jar:2.3.8.RELEASE]
> at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:758) ~[spring-boot-2.3.8.RELEASE.jar:2.3.8.RELEASE]
> at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:750) [spring-boot-2.3.8.RELEASE.jar:2.3.8.RELEASE]
> at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refreshContext(SpringApplication.java:405) [spring-boot-2.3.8.RELEASE.jar:2.3.8.RELEASE]
> at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:315) [spring-boot-2.3.8.RELEASE.jar:2.3.8.RELEASE]
> at com.satish.NriAssetMgmtServiceApplication.main(NriAssetMgmtServiceApplication.java:28) [classes/:?]
> Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Unresolvable class definition for class [com.satishch.microspace.nri.security.ReferenceSecurityConfig]
> at org.springframework.util.ClassUtils.resolveClassName(ClassUtils.java:331) ~[spring-core-5.2.12.RELEASE.jar:5.2.12.RELEASE]
> at org.springframework.security.config.annotation.method.configuration.GlobalMethodSecuritySelector.selectImports(GlobalMethodSecuritySelector.java:51) ~[spring-security-config-5.3.6.RELEASE.jar:5.3.6.RELEASE]
> at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassParser.processImports(ConfigurationClassParser.java:581) ~[spring-context-5.2.12.RELEASE.jar:5.2.12.RELEASE]
> ... 21 more
> Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/springframework/security/oauth2/config/annotation/web/configuration/ResourceServerConfigurerAdapter
> at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass1(Native Method) ~[?:1.8.0_191]
> at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(ClassLoader.java:763) ~[?:1.8.0_191]
> at java.security.SecureClassLoader.defineClass(SecureClassLoader.java:142) ~[?:1.8.0_191]
> at java.net.URLClassLoader.defineClass(URLClassLoader.java:468) ~[?:1.8.0_191]
> at java.net.URLClassLoader.access$100(URLClassLoader.java:74) ~[?:1.8.0_191]
> at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:369) ~[?:1.8.0_191]
> at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:363) ~[?:1.8.0_191]
> at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method) ~[?:1.8.0_191]
> at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:362) ~[?:1.8.0_191]
> at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:424) ~[?:1.8.0_191]
> at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:349) ~[?:1.8.0_191]
> at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:357) ~[?:1.8.0_191]
> at java.lang.Class.forName0(Native Method) ~[?:1.8.0_191]
> at java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:348) ~[?:1.8.0_191]
> at org.springframework.util.ClassUtils.forName(ClassUtils.java:284) ~[spring-core-5.2.12.RELEASE.jar:5.2.12.RELEASE]
> at org.springframework.util.ClassUtils.resolveClassName(ClassUtils.java:324) ~[spring-core-5.2.12.RELEASE.jar:5.2.12.RELEASE]
> at org.springframework.security.config.annotation.method.configuration.GlobalMethodSecuritySelector.selectImports(GlobalMethodSecuritySelector.java:51) ~[spring-security-config-5.3.6.RELEASE.jar:5.3.6.RELEASE]
> at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassParser.processImports(ConfigurationClassParser.java:581) ~[spring-context-5.2.12.RELEASE.jar:5.2.12.RELEASE]
> ... 21 more
> Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.springframework.security.oauth2.config.annotation.web.configuration.ResourceServerConfigurerAdapter
> at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:382) ~[?:1.8.0_191]
> at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:424) ~[?:1.8.0_191]
> at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:349) ~[?:1.8.0_191]
> at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:357) ~[?:1.8.0_191]
> at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass1(Native Method) ~[?:1.8.0_191]
> at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(ClassLoader.java:763) ~[?:1.8.0_191]
> at java.security.SecureClassLoader.defineClass(SecureClassLoader.java:142) ~[?:1.8.0_191]
> at java.net.URLClassLoader.defineClass(URLClassLoader.java:468) ~[?:1.8.0_191]
> at java.net.URLClassLoader.access$100(URLClassLoader.java:74) ~[?:1.8.0_191]
> at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:369) ~[?:1.8.0_191]
> at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:363) ~[?:1.8.0_191]
> at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method) ~[?:1.8.0_191]
> at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:362) ~[?:1.8.0_191]
> at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:424) ~[?:1.8.0_191]
> at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:349) ~[?:1.8.0_191]
> at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:357) ~[?:1.8.0_191]
> at java.lang.Class.forName0(Native Method) ~[?:1.8.0_191]
> at java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:348) ~[?:1.8.0_191]
> at org.springframework.util.ClassUtils.forName(ClassUtils.java:284) ~[spring-core-5.2.12.RELEASE.jar:5.2.12.RELEASE]
> at org.springframework.util.ClassUtils.resolveClassName(ClassUtils.java:324) ~[spring-core-5.2.12.RELEASE.jar:5.2.12.RELEASE]
> at org.springframework.security.config.annotation.method.configuration.GlobalMethodSecuritySelector.selectImports(GlobalMethodSecuritySelector.java:51) ~[spring-security-config-5.3.6.RELEASE.jar:5.3.6.RELEASE]
> at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassParser.processImports(ConfigurationClassParser.java:581) ~[spring-context-5.2.12.RELEASE.jar:5.2.12.RELEASE]
> ... 21 more
> ```

2. Creating annotation interface inside the library importing the config class. And, adding the annotation in any project in main class.

> For the full error stacktrace, please see the following collapsed snippet:
>
> ```js
> 12:34:17.903 [main] ERROR org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication - Application run failed
> org.springframework.context.ApplicationContextException: Unable to start web server; nested exception is org.springframework.context.ApplicationContextException: Unable to start ServletWebServerApplicationContext due to missing ServletWebServerFactory bean.
> at org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.context.ServletWebServerApplicationContext.onRefresh(ServletWebServerApplicationContext.java:161) ~[spring-boot-2.3.8.RELEASE.jar:2.3.8.RELEASE]
> at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:545) ~[spring-context-5.2.12.RELEASE.jar:5.2.12.RELEASE]
> at org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.context.ServletWebServerApplicationContext.refresh(ServletWebServerApplicationContext.java:143) ~[spring-boot-2.3.8.RELEASE.jar:2.3.8.RELEASE]
> at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:758) ~[spring-boot-2.3.8.RELEASE.jar:2.3.8.RELEASE]
> at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:750) [spring-boot-2.3.8.RELEASE.jar:2.3.8.RELEASE]
> at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refreshContext(SpringApplication.java:405) [spring-boot-2.3.8.RELEASE.jar:2.3.8.RELEASE]
> at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:315) [spring-boot-2.3.8.RELEASE.jar:2.3.8.RELEASE]
> at com.satish.AssetMgmtServiceApplication.main(AssetMgmtServiceApplication.java:31) [classes/:?]
> Caused by: org.springframework.context.ApplicationContextException: Unable to start ServletWebServerApplicationContext due to missing ServletWebServerFactory bean.
> at org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.context.ServletWebServerApplicationContext.getWebServerFactory(ServletWebServerApplicationContext.java:205) ~[spring-boot-2.3.8.RELEASE.jar:2.3.8.RELEASE]
> at org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.context.ServletWebServerApplicationContext.createWebServer(ServletWebServerApplicationContext.java:177) ~[spring-boot-2.3.8.RELEASE.jar:2.3.8.RELEASE]
> at org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.context.ServletWebServerApplicationContext.onRefresh(ServletWebServerApplicationContext.java:158) ~[spring-boot-2.3.8.RELEASE.jar:2.3.8.RELEASE]
> ... 7 more
> ```

**Source code:**

resoruces/META-INF/spring.factories (1st Approach)

```
 org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.EnableAutoConfiguration=\
 com.satish.security.ReferenceSecurityConfig
```

Config inside the library

```
@EnableGlobalMethodSecurity(prePostEnabled = true)
@EnableResourceServer
@EnableWebSecurity
@Configuration
@ConfigurationProperties(prefix = "security")
@Data
@EqualsAndHashCode(callSuper=false)
public class ReferenceSecurityConfig extends ResourceServerConfigurerAdapter {

    private boolean bypass;
    
    @Override
    public void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {

        http
        .cors()
        .and()
        .csrf().disable();

        if (bypass) {
            http.authorizeRequests().antMatchers("/**").permitAll();
        } else {
            http.authorizeRequests()
            .antMatchers("/swagger-ui/**").permitAll()
            .antMatchers("/management").permitAll()
            .antMatchers("/management/**").permitAll()
            .antMatchers("/swagger-ui.html").permitAll()
            .antMatchers("/swagger-resources/**").permitAll()
            .antMatchers("/v2/api-docs/**").permitAll()
            .antMatchers("/webjars/**").permi tAll()
            .antMatchers("/v3/api-docs/**").permitAll()
            .antMatchers("/swagger-ui/**").permitAll()
            .antMatchers("/**").authenticated();
        }
    }
}
```

Annotation to use in the main project (2nd approach)

```
@Retention(RetentionPolicy.RUNTIME)
@Target(ElementType.TYPE)
@Import(ReferenceSecurityConfig.class)
public @interface EnableCustomSecurityConfig {
}
```

pom.xml

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 https://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <groupId>com.satish</groupId>
    <artifactId>core-lib</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <name>core-lib</name>
    <description>Storing common implementation</description>

    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>2.3.8.RELEASE</version>
        <relativePath />
    </parent>


    <properties>
        <java.version>1.8</java.version>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
        <log4j2.version>2.17.1</log4j2.version>
        <log4j2Version>2.7</log4j2Version>
        <slf4jVersion>1.7.21</slf4jVersion>
    </properties>

    <repositories>
        <repository>
            <id>confluent</id>
            <url>https://packages.confluent.io/maven/</url>
        </repository>
    </repositories>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
            <version>2.2.1.RELEASE</version>
            <type>pom</type>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <!-- security dependencies -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.security.oauth.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-security-oauth2-autoconfigure</artifactId>
            <version>2.3.4.RELEASE</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-oauth2-resource-server</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
          <groupId>org.springframework.security.oauth</groupId>
          <artifactId>spring-security-oauth2</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-security-oauth2-core</artifactId>
            <version>5.1.7.RELEASE</version>
            <optional>true</optional>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-security-core</artifactId>
            <version>${springSecurityVersion}</version>
        </dependency>
        <!-- spring-boot-starter-security -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>slf4j-api</artifactId>
            <optional>true</optional>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>jcl-over-slf4j</artifactId>
            <optional>true</optional>
        </dependency>
        <!-- Not sure why Lombok is not working -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.projectlombok</groupId>
            <artifactId>lombok</artifactId>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>
        <!-- Provided Dependencies -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-configuration-processor</artifactId>
            <optional>true</optional>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-jar-plugin</artifactId>
                <configuration>
                    <archive>
                        <manifestEntries>
                            <Implementation-Vendor>Satish's Companies Inc.</Implementation-Vendor>
                            <Implementation-Title>TITLE</Implementation-Title>
                            <Implementation-Version>2.2</Implementation-Version>
                        </manifestEntries>
                    </archive>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
            <!--plugin> <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId> <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId> 
                <configuration> <fork>true</fork> <mainClass>${start-class}</mainClass> </configuration> 
                <executions> <execution> <goals> <goal>repackage</goal> </goals> </execution> 
                </executions> </plugin -->
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-source-plugin</artifactId>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <id>attach-sources</id>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>jar</goal>
                        </goals>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>
</project>
```

Comment: Do you import dependency `spring-security-oauth2`  in your maven pom file?

Comment: yes in the library jar. Let me add the pom file here

Comment: Can you please comment why isn't the answer satisfying? Otherwise, would you accept the answer?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, I believe I already did a lib [achieving what you're trying to do](https://github.com/ch4mpy/spring-addons/tree/master/webmvc/spring-addons-webmvc-jwt-resource-server). A lot is configurable from properties (CORS, authorities mapping and more) and it is published on maven-central.

Spring-boot starters have [changed since 2.7](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/wiki/Spring-Boot-2.7-Release-Notes#building-jars-with-maven-shade-plugin-and-gradle-shadow-plugin).

Auto-configured components should now be:

- decorated with `@AutoConfiguration`
- declared in `META-INF/spring/org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.AutoConfiguration.imports`

Minimal sample [here](https://github.com/ch4mpy/spring-addons/tree/master/starters/spring-addons-starters-webclient) with [this resource](https://github.com/ch4mpy/spring-addons/blob/master/starters/spring-addons-starters-webclient/src/main/resources/META-INF/spring/org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.AutoConfiguration.imports)

```
com.c4_soft.springaddons.starter.webclient.SpringBootAutoConfiguration
```

and that [loaded file](https://github.com/ch4mpy/spring-addons/blob/master/starters/spring-addons-starters-webclient/src/main/java/com/c4_soft/springaddons/starter/webclient/SpringBootAutoConfiguration.java)

```java
package com.c4_soft.springaddons.starter.webclient;

import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.AutoConfiguration;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Import;

@AutoConfiguration
@Import({ C4ProxySettings.class, C4WebClientBuilderFactoryService.class })
public class SpringBootAutoConfiguration {
}
```

Comment: sorry for the late response. I had shifted to a different work. The thing which worked for me is since my lib jar is a small 5-6 kb. So, I haven't hosted it in a repository. Adding the jar file in the required service like the local repository & mentioning it in pom.xml worked. The only thing is import jar didn't work directly. Else no changes in the lib jar